# Is it possible to store multiple values in an excel cell?

Tags: excel

So I'm doing an analysis of values in a database and I figured the simplest way to do this is to use a pivot table. The problem I have is that some of the categories have multiple values in them. To show what I mean, I've included a sample of my excel file in this link: [Excel Sample](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vxx4fiv8cydexci/Sample.xlsx?dl=0).

What I want to be able to do with my pivot is to, for example, filter Exposure Class by "N" and have all three entries with "N" show up. Is it possible to do this? I do have to note that this analysis doesn't have to be done in a pivot but the pivot does make the rest of the analysis a lot easier.

Answer (score 9):

Short answer: No -- each Excel cell contains a single value

Long answer: Yes, of course! That single value can be a delimited string which splits into multiple fields, each of which corresponds to a value. Also, you can smuggle information into a cell using comments, formatting, etc. -- although such information isn't easy to manipulate without VBA.

If the data in the cell looks something like "C2, S1, N" you can test if something like "S2" appears in it. Say that the string is in `A1`. Then the following formula returns `TRUE` or `FALSE` depending in whether or not `S2` appears in it:

```
=IF(IFERROR(SEARCH("S2",A1),0) > 0, TRUE, FALSE)
```

(`SEARCH` isn't case-sensitive. Use `FIND` if you want a case-sensitive search).
I don't have a lot of experience with pivot tables but I know that it is possible to filter a pivot table by a formula. You should be able to pull up all records in which e.g. "S2" appears in it.

Comment: So I guess pivot tables are not the best tool for analyzing my data?

Comment: @JianYang Should still be possible. See my edit for a hopefully helpful idea.

Comment: The problem I see with this solution is that there are 11 potential values within the category and filtering by specific values means I will have to create separate filters for each of the values. Being that this is not the only category with cells containing multiple values, it's going to get very cluttered very soon if I start doing that. But thank you for the idea anyways.